# Word Problem Involving Velocities, Acceleration, Limits

Tags: calculus, integration

This is the problem:

[image]

I took the integral of a(t) to get v(t) and got $v(t)$ = $\ln(t+2)$ $-$ $\ln(t+3)$ + C . I plugged in the initial conditions and got C = 0. Then when I took the limit, I know it's a telescoping series so everything cancels out except the $\ln(2)$ but that's not an answer choice so I'm confused what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I assume that the initial velocity refers to $v(0) = \ln \frac{2}{3}$:
$$v(t) = \ln \frac{t+2}{t+3} = \ln \frac{1+\frac{2}{t}}{1+\frac{3}{t}}\stackrel{t \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\ln 1 = 0$$

Comment: That makes sense. However, why doesn't using the fact that they're telescopic work in this case?

Comment: @krauser126 Could you please write down the telescoping sum you are referring to? This might clear up what went wrong.

Comment: [ln (2) + ln(3) + ln(4) + ...]  -  [ln (3) + ln (4) + ln (5) + ...]   Since its from t = 0 to t = infinity. So wouldnt all the terms in the negative set cancel with those equivalent in the positive set, leaving + ln(2) as the first term left over.

Comment: @krauser126 This expression would be adding the velocities at specific points: $v(0) + v(1) + \cdots $ and does not represent the limit for $t \to \infty$

Comment: @krauser126 Besides this: what you wrote is an undefined expression: $\infty - \infty$. If you set $v(k) = \ln (k+2) - \ln (k+3)$ you would get $$\Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^n v(k) = \sum_{k=0}^n (\ln (k+2) - \ln (k+3)) =  
\ln 2 - \ln (n+3)$$
Now ask yourself whether this reflects the question to be answered.

Comment: Got it! I confused the concept of finding the limit with finding the sum of a series.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. And now you found it out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have 
$$
v(t)=\ln\tfrac23+\int_0^t\frac1{u^2+5u+6}\,du=\ln\tfrac23+\ln\frac{t+2}{t+3}+\ln\tfrac32,
$$
where the   $\ln \tfrac32$ comes from evaluating the antiderivative at $0$. Then 
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}v(t)=\ln \tfrac23+\ln \tfrac32=0. 
$$

Comment: I didn't understand a thing you did. Doesn't it tell us that the velocity is initially ln(2/3) so that we can use that as an initial condition to plug t = 0 and solve for C, which I did already and got C = 0. So why did you do that additional step.

Comment: Now I see that I misread something. Give me a second.

Comment: You can do it as I did, or you find that $C=0$. In any case, the limit is zero.